# Pandas select data between both index and value range

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I wish to set the values of a dataframe that lie between an index range and a value range to be `NaN` values. For example, say I have `n` columns, I want for every numeric data point in these columns to be set to `NaN` if they meet the following conditions:

- The value is between -1 and 1
- The index of this value is between 1 and 3

Below I have some code that is trying to do what I'm describing above, and it almost does it, it's just that it is setting these values on a copy of the original dataframe, and trying to use `.loc` throws the following error:

> KeyError: "None of [Index([('a',), ('b',), ('c',)], dtype='object')]
> are in the [columns]"

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


np.random.seed(398)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 3), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])


row_indexer = (df.index > 0) & (df.index < 4)
col_indexer = (df > -1) & (df < 1)


df[row_indexer][col_indexer] = np.nan
```

I'm sure there's a really simple solution, I just can't figure out the correct syntax.

(Additionally, I want to "extract" these filtered values (the ones I'm setting to `NaN`) into a second dataframe, but I'm fairly sure any solution that solves the primary question will solve this additional issue)

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: `col_indexer = (df > -1) & (df < 1)` returns a dataframe, not `col_index` like `row_index`. Is it intentional?

Comment: @QuangHoang Not so much intentional, I just don't know of any other way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try broadcasting with numpy:

```
df[row_indexer[:,None] & col_indexer] = np.nan
```

Output:

```
          a         b         c
0 -1.810802 -0.776590 -0.495147
1  1.381038       NaN  2.334671
2       NaN -1.571401  1.011139
3 -1.200217 -1.013983       NaN
4  1.261759  0.863896  0.228914
```

Comment: Thankyou! Can you explain why this works?

Comment: have a look at [numpy documention](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#:~:text=The%20term%20broadcasting%20describes%20how%20numpy%20treats%20arrays,that%20looping%20occurs%20in%20C%20instead%20of%20Python.) for broacasting.

Answer (score 0):

I will do `mul` since True * True = True

```
out = df.mask(col_indexer.mul(row_indexer ,axis=0))
Out[81]: 
          a         b         c
0 -1.810802 -0.776590 -0.495147
1  1.381038       NaN  2.334671
2       NaN -1.571401  1.011139
3 -1.200217 -1.013983       NaN
4  1.261759  0.863896  0.228914
```